# Bing Ads API retrieve configured budget

Tags: python, ads, bing

I need to retrieve the current values for the configured budget per campaign.  The closest thing I've found is this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/reporting-service/budgetsummaryreportcolumn

Unfortunately I'm not trying to find the amount that has been spent, just what the current budget has been set to per campaign.  Is there any way to retrieve this data using the Bing Ads API v11?

Note: I'd prefer using the Bing Python SDK to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered you can use the bulk service manager from Bing Python SDK to download data related to campaigns.  This data contains the currently configured budget for the campaign.  I had to adapt the following example:

https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-Python-SDK/blob/V11.5.3/examples/BingAdsPythonConsoleExamples/BingAdsPythonConsoleExamples/v11/bulk_service_manager_demo.py